# Using Forms in Laravel without including LaravelCollective

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Since Laravel collective has been shutdown and is not available, how can we use forms in the laravel framework?

Comment: Laravel Collective is not available anymore to include the 'Form' class. Both the links are not valid. @MjM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
 <?php
    echo '<form action="page.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="CourseID" value="'.$Array[0].'"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="Edit">
    </form>';
?>
```